# Generate 2 dimensional permutations of a python list

Tags: python

I have a python list as follows:

```
[['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1'],['row_1','row_1_0','row_1_1']]
```

where each list in the parent list is called a `row` and each item in child list is called a `column`. 
For example: `['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1']` is a row.
and 'row_0','row_0_0' and 'row_0_1' are columns of this row.

I want to generate permutations in such a way that

1. The total number of rows remain the same as in the original parent list i.e,2.
2. The permutations of the columns of each row remain within that row. For example: `['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1']` can have a permutation `['row_0','row_0_1','row_0_0']`, `['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1']`.
3. The first column of each row never changes in permutations. For example: 'row_0' in and 'row_1' always remain the first items in their list.

So far what I have implemented looks like this:

```
perm_list =  [['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1'],['row_1','row_1_0','row_1_1']]
all_permutations = list(itertools.permutations(perm_list, len(perm_list))
print(all_permutations)
```

but this only generates permutations at the parent list level. I was wondering if python has a builtin tool to handle a functionality like this that can be tweaked to fit my needs. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The output I am looking for is something like this:

```
[
  [['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1'],['row_1','row_1_0','row_1_1']],
  [['row_0','row_0_1','row_0_0'],['row_1','row_1_1','row_1_0']],
  [['row_1','row_1_0','row_1_1'],['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1']],
  [['row_1','row_1_1','row_1_0'],['row_0','row_0_1','row_0_0']],
]
```

a. The first item in each child list remained the same.
b. The items in each child list remained within that list.
c. The total number of items for both parent and child list remained the same.

Comment: It looks like you just want to do `itertools.permutations()` twice or at a different nesting level. Perhaps, having a couple of concrete inputs and expected outputs would be more clear.

Comment: or if you do not want to permute twice, reshape to 1d, permute and interpret as 2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know , there is no build-in function for what you described

```
l1=[[list((x[0],)+y) for y in itertools.permutations(x[1:], len(x)-1)] for x in l ]
list(map(list,itertools.product(l1[0],l1[1])))
[[['row_0', 'row_0_0', 'row_0_1'], ['row_1', 'row_1_0', 'row_1_1']], 
[['row_0', 'row_0_0', 'row_0_1'], ['row_1', 'row_1_1', 'row_1_0']], 
[['row_0', 'row_0_1', 'row_0_0'], ['row_1', 'row_1_0', 'row_1_1']], 
[['row_0', 'row_0_1', 'row_0_0'], ['row_1', 'row_1_1', 'row_1_0']]]
```

Comment: You're creating a third list here in the form of tuple. It should remain nested at a level of 2.

Comment: @sshussain270 would you like show us the expected output

Comment: @sshussain270 you may need one more steps `product`

Comment: This will do the trick! Not sure why all of the the list and their children list have been converted to tuples. If you make it produce lists than tuples, I can mark it as correct

Comment: @WeNYoBen By the way, the call to `list` on the result of `permutations` is unnecessary because you are iterating through it anyway.

Comment: @WeNYoBen it has to be workable with my other code which demands it to be a list. BTW what does  l at the end of your first line of code mean?

Comment: @sshussain270 l = [['row_0','row_0_0','row_0_1'],['row_1','row_1_0','row_1_1']]

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad!

Comment: @WeNYoBen your solution breaks if there are any lesser number of items in the child lists than 3, for example: `l = [['row_0', 'row_0_0'], ['row_1', 'row_1_0']]` - this should give the output of `[[['row_0', 'row_0_0'], ['row_1', 'row_1_0']], [['row_1', 'row_1_0'],['row_0', 'row_0_0']]]`

Comment: @sshussain270 that is the exceptions you just need `list(map(list,itertools.product(l[0],l[1])))
`